# Travis-ci predefine container infrastructure

Tags: opencv, continuous-integration, travis-ci

I have a problem with too long builds on travis-ci. 
The reason, is building of opencv library.

Can I some how configure travis, not to rebuild it every time?

Answer (score 0):

Found out solution.

Travis-ci provides caching of information.
http://docs.travis-ci.com/user/caching/